# Writing/Reading arrays or Stringarrays in Parcelable

Tags: java, android, parcel

In order to pass an object between 2 activities in my app, i made the class implement Parcable and everything works fine. Now I want to extend this class with an Array of String Arrays (String[][]).

I searched the internet for some time but i couldn't find a way to handle this at `writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)` and in the Constructor `MyClass(Parcel in)`.

Another option would be to create a class with just 2 Strings stringA and stringB and let that class implement Parcable, too. Then i could use readList() and writeList() to write lists of that Parcables but this doesnt seem to be an ideal solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Couldn't you just loop over the array-of-`String[]` and write out every `String[]` using `writeStringArray(String[] val)`? For reading you obviously use the appropriate counterpart. You may have to write out the size of the array-of-String[]'s first, so that you can easily reconstruct the whole thing when reading back in the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Parcel class has a writeStringArray() method. Couldn't your class iterate over the String[][] and call writeStringArray for each?

Assuming your class has a member:

```
String[][] data;
```

in writeToParcel()

```
parcel.writeInt(data.length);
for( int i=0; i<data.lengh; i++ ){
    parcel.writeStringArray(data[i]);
}
```

in createFromParcel()

```
int size = parcel.readInt();
data = new String[size][];
for( int i=0; i<size; i++ ){
  data[i] = parcel.readStringArray();
}
```